# C multiplying and dividing

Tags: c, division, multiplication

I am running a program for school and am running into a simple math problem that C is not calculating correctly.  I am simply trying to divide my output by a number and it is returning the original number.

```
int main(void)
{
    float fcost = 599;
    float shipt =  (fcost / 120);
    shipt = shipt * 120;

    printf("%4.0f", shipt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return 0;)`... ___seriously___??

Comment: ? do you know what `shipt *= 120;` does? Why did you put it there?

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags! C++ is a different language!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The program is doing what is is _programmed for_. Don't blame the poor language/code. :)

Comment: That code looks like copy/pasted snippets from different sources. Maybe you better listen to what your teacher says.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If I would invent a new language there would be much more `;)` and `:)` rather than the sad looking `};` and `);`

Comment: What dou you expect and what do you get ?

Comment: Do you not realize that the `shipt *=120;` is the inverse of `float shipt = (fcost / 120);`?

Comment: Im just trying to multiply shipt by 120. and everyt ime i do the result is the original output of fcost.

Comment: @AnthonyBahlman Exactly as it should, since you first divide `fcost` by 120 then multiply the result by 120.

Comment: What you are actually calculating is `599 / 120 * 120`. Interestingly, that's 599.

Comment: There is a good chance that the compiler optimizes everything away and the program just prints 599 without doing anything. Also: 599/120 is 4.9916666666... in decimal but also in binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what was stated in the comments, you want the result of the division to be rounded down.

In order to do that, you should use `int` instead of `float` so that integer division is performed (which truncates the fractional part) instead of floating point division (which retains the fractional part):

```
int fcost = 599;
int shipt =  (fcost / 120);
shipt *=120;

printf("%d", shipt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply divide the number by 120, remove the next line, i.e remove

shipt*=120

As it nullifies the previous line's process.

In the event this isn't what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: the result of the number and 120 i want to multiply by 120 as well i even tried all in one line.such as shipt = 120 * (fcost /120)

Comment: See, consider it this way. I have 5 apples costing a total of 20$. Now, if I find the individual cost of 1 apple, I get that its 4$. Now, basically since I bought 5 apples, I spend a total of 5*4$, which is 20$ which is what you're displaying. See how redundant the code is?

Comment: yea isee that but what im trying to do is divide 599 by 120 the result being 4 and multiply 4 by 120 which will be 480. the program i have im divide disks in boxes of 12. and those boxes only shipp in cases of 120. you see where im going with this?

Comment: Ah alright, now I see the issue. All you need to change in your code, is that you need to change the data type of shipt from float to int or try type casting the division operation. Do I make sense to you?

Comment: that resulted in 0 when i changed it to int

Comment: type casting? what is that.

Comment: nevermind i got it ifeel dumb sorry for bothering you with a dumb question.

Comment: This is an example of type casting - float shipt=int(fcost/120); that is, you intentionally convert the result to an integer, which in this case will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

OP appears to [want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598062/c-multiplying-and-dividing#comment66505977_39598639) a truncated number quotient.

Converting a FP number to `int` risks undefined behavior (UB) if the original `double` is much outside the range of `int`.

The standard library provides various rounding functions to avoid the above problem.

```
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float fcost = 599;
    // to round to the next lower whole number
    float shipt =  floorf(fcost / 120);
    // to round to the next higher whole number
    float shipt =  ceilf(fcost / 120);
    // to round to the next whole number toward 0
    float shipt =  truncf(fcost / 120);

    shipt *= 120;
    printf("%4.0f", shipt);
    return 0;
}
```